# Foreign Key - One Child Table to Multiple Parent Tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have 2 parent tables (media, ads) and 1 child table (paths). Each value in any of parent table (media or ads) can contain links to multiple values in paths table. 
When I try to insert value in 'paths' I get an error below. This would work if I have 2 'path' tables (path_media, path_ads), one for each of parent tables and set 1 foreign key restraint for each child-parent table, but why do I have to duplicate table paths instead of restraining them with FK?

//create tables

```
CREATE TABLE `media` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `title` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `ads` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `description` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `paths` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `media_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `media_id` (`media_id`)
);
```

//add 2 foreign keys

```
ALTER TABLE `paths`
ADD CONSTRAINT `paths_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`) REFERENCES `media`   (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `paths_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`) REFERENCES `ads` (`id`);
```

//sql query

```
INSERT INTO paths (path, media_id)
                    VALUES (?, ?)");
```

//error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`paths`, CONSTRAINT `paths_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`) REFERENCES `ads` (`id`))"
```

Comment: If you define those two FKs, you can only insert a new path row if the new `paths.media_id` exists in both tables (`media` and `ads`). However it doesn't look reasonable to me what you are doing.

Comment: I understand, but I got into this 'mess' by adding FK. Now I will have to make 2 paths tables (each referencing media/ads individually with FK). Since I have other tables like paths, I will have to duplicate them all. This may be safer because of FK, but it look to me like lot more data to handle. Not sure if all this is worth it (FK)

Comment: Maybe you want to define the FKs the other way around. `media.path_id references paths.id` and `ads.path_id references paths.id`

Answer (score 0):

Here, table `path` should be the parent table and tables `media` and `ads` should be the two child tables.

```
ALTER TABLE `media`
    -> ADD CONSTRAINT `paths_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `paths` (`media_id`);
```

```
ALTER TABLE `ads`
    -> ADD CONSTRAINT `paths_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `paths` (`media_id`);
```

```
INSERT INTO `paths` VALUES (1, "abc", 1);
```